# Not able to get the firebase user custom details into .ts file using realtime database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the custom details of firebase user from Realtime database.
I'm able to retrieve the details and able to print it in console from service.ts file.

I want to export those details to .ts file so I can use it

service file

```
getDetails(){
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
     if (user) {
         var getUserInfo = firebase.database().ref("users/" + user.uid);
         getUserInfo.once("value", function(snapshot) {
         console.log(snapshot.val());
           });
       }
    }
```

.ts file

```
  ngOnInit(){
   this.authService.getDetails();
  }
```

custom details available in database are 
city, mobile etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return the promise from the service

```
  getDetails(){
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
     if (user) {
         var getUserInfo = firebase.database().ref("users/" + user.uid);
         return getUserInfo.once("value")
    }
```

resolve it from the component

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.authService.getDetails()then(function(snapshot) { 
         console.log(snapshot.val());

   });
  }
```

Comment: I'm able to print in console but I'm not able to retrieve like    data:any;   this.data=snapshot.val(); throwing error it is same when trying to pass it as an object